Исключить повторение
Есть 2 записи:
fdag.alt.alt
gyajj.alt
Необходимо развести их через регулярное выражение (вхождение буквы a + окончание). Но они обе попадают под первый шаблон - заканчиваются на .alt.
Нужно, чтобы, если заканчивается просто на .alt - 1 вариант, а если именно на .alt.alt - второй. Возможно так сделать?
with ds as
(
    select 'fdag.alt.alt' v
    union 
    select 'gyajj.alt'
)
select
    ds.v ~* '.*a.*\.alt$' v1,
    ds.v ~* '.*a.*\.alt.alt$' v2,
    ds.* 
from ds;


(ds.v ~* '.*a.*\.alt$') :: INT + (ds.v ~* '.*a.*\.alt.alt$') :: INT AS amount

Только так, посчитав количество и проанализировав? Мне нужно, к сожалению, сделать одним шаблоном. Шаблоны - в БД, на логику выборки могу влиять только через них (((

Один шаблон может сказать либо ДА, либо НЕТ. То есть всего два варианта. У тебя же их как минимум три - несоответствие, соответствие одному из двух, соответствие обоим.

Ну да. Два шаблона соответственно. Как в примере. Но за подсказку в комментарии выше спасибо, теперь учту, что и алгоритмически можно сравнивать результаты шаблонов, расширил немного взгляд на это ))

Впрочем, никто не мешает получить что-то вроде array_length(regexp_split_to_array(ds.v, '\.alt'), 1) AS value_type

Разобрался с отрицаниями. Если есть еще варианты, буду рад изучить их.
Вот результат:
with ds as
(
    select 'fdag.alt.alt' v
    union 
    select 'gyajj.alt'
)
select
    ds.v ~* '.*a.*[^\.alt]\.alt$' v1,
    ds.v ~* '.*a.*\.alt\.alt$' v2,
    ds.* 
from ds;

